# In Celery, how do I run a task, and then have that task run another task, and keep it going?

Tags: python, django, data-structures, asynchronous, celery

```
#tasks.py
from celery.task import Task
class Randomer(Task):
    def run(self, **kwargs):
        #run Randomer again!!!
        return random.randrange(0,1000000)


>>> from tasks import Randomer
>>> r = Randomer()
>>> r.delay()
```

Right now, I run the simple task. And it returns a random number.  But, how do I make it run another task , **inside that task**?

Comment: Why would you like to do this? Are you trying to implement something like a crontab or a watchdog? If so this question is an instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and it would be more productive asking about the original problem you are trying to solve instead of asking about how to implement the solution you devised.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call `other_task.delay()` from inside `Randomer.run`; in this case you may want to set `Randomer.ignore_result = True` (and `other_task.ignore_result`, and so on).

Remember that celery tasks `delay` returns instantly, so if you don't put any limit or wait time on the nested calls (or recursive calls), you can reach meltdown pretty quickly.

Instead of recursion or nested tasks, you should consider an infinite loop to avoid stack overflow (no pun intended).

```
from celery.task import Task
class Randomer(Task):
    def run(self, **kwargs):
        while True:
           do_something(**kwargs)
           time.sleep(600)
```

Comment: can you show an example code? I don't quite get what you mean

Comment: But I want do_something to be "Randomer()".  I could add a delay in it, so that it doesn't continously go and go without break.  Are you saying I have to write another function called "do_something", that is identical to the randomer class?

Comment: By 'do_something' I mean whatever is Randomers real work. If you want something going on and on, you need a loop, not a queue; perhaps I'm wrong, it's hard to tell from the sample you posted. Putting an infinite recursive call inside a task is dangerous, you can consume all the computer resources pretty fast (meltdown).

Answer (score 2):

You can chain subtasks as described here: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains

Comment: chains are something like ,when you execute first task and want to feed  its result that into second task , you should chain those tasks. But question here is different.  chaining is like piping one task result into another. I think questioner intention is about solving nested task calls.

Comment: I guess OP wants to implement something like a crontab or watchdog and a task queue is not the best foundation for that.