# Config celery to start task again after it has been finished

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

How I can config celery to get one worker always run the same task. And after it ended starts it again on the same worker.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you will need to take two steps

1. [Create a separate queue](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#guide-routing) for this task, [route](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#message-routing) the task to the queue

2a. Create an infinite loop that calls your particular task, such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4553513/3130972)

OR

2b. Have a recursive task that calls itself on completion (this could get messy)